# How to check Jenkins build executor free memory?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, monitoring

In Jenkins when clicking on *Build Executor Status* I can only see free disk space related statistics (URI: `/computer`). How I can monitor free system memory (RAM) in Jenkins?

I'm asking, because sometimes when I had too many executors (despite having swap space configured, but not the one below), Jenkins was freezing or crashing a lot.

[image: Jenkins at /computer - Name, Architecture, Clock Difference, Free Disk Space, Free Swap Space, Free Temp Space, Response Time]

Comment: You may find the monitoring plugin helpful: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring

Comment: Side note: heavy swapping will bring even the most powerful servers to a crawl, slowing down all processes, including the Jenkins executors and local monitoring solutions. To make matters worse: the memory garbage collectors will also run slow, further feeding the condition. For decent performance I'd advice keeping the swap size small-ish, relying primarily on the actual RAM size when sharing the same server for multiple executors and avoiding heavy over-subscription.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have a look at the [Monitoring](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring) plugin. Here are some more details about it (from the linked page):

> - Charts of memory, cpu, system load average, http response times by day, week, month, year or custom period
> - Statistics of http requests with mean response times, mean cpu times, mean response size by request and by day, week, month, year or custom period
> - Errors and logs
> - Current http requests
> - Threads
> - Heap histogram (instances and sizes by class)
> - Http sessions
> - Process list of OS
> - MBeans
> - Actions for GC, heap dump and invalidate session(s)
> - Report in html or pdf
> - In English, German, French, Portuguese or Chinese
> - Jenkins security
> - For Jenkins nodes (slaves in general):
>
>   - The report for the nodes is available at `http://yourhost/monitoring/nodes`
>   - Charts aggregated for all nodes of memory, cpu, system load average, number of running builds, build queue length, build times by period
>   - Detailed statistics of the build times and of the build steps by period
>   - Threads, process list and MBeans for each nodes
>   - Heap histogram aggregated for all nodes
> - For each individual node (each node in `http://yourhost/computer`), reports and actions are available from the "Monitoring" page in the contextual menu or in the detail of the node:
>
>   - Threads, process list, MBeans of that node only
>   - Heap histogram of that node
>   - Actions for GC, heap dump
> - And more...

Credits: [Assaf Lavie](https://devops.stackexchange.com/users/2/assaf-lavie) (who first mentioned it in a comment, but for some reason didn't post that as an actual answer ...).

Answer (score 5):

As for workaround, the actual memory can be checked by invoking Groovy commands directly in *Script Console* (at `/computer/(master)/script`). Example command:

```
println "free -m".execute().text
```

Comment: Alternative command: `awk '/MemFree:/ { print $2}' /proc/meminfo` for kB free of ram only or alternative for Memory and Swap: `awk '/(Mem|Swap)Free:/ { print }' /proc/meminfo`

Comment: I am not sure if awk scripts can be executed via Jenkins script console. As I can see, Jenkins script console is for Groovy only